# How to cumulate texts at the end into various groups?

Tags: macros, memoir

Please help:
I am editing a `.tex` file (memoir class) with lot of text, and I want to collect sentences like important questions, quotes, words, etc and collect them into their respective groups and be able to put them end of the book.

For example:

---

`.tex` file

```
\chapter{xyz}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam metus massa, molestie elementum tincidunt at, mollis et quam.
\collectQuestion{Donec viverra posuere lorem, ac sagittis eros tincidunt interdum?}
Phasellus feugiat id justo at pretium. 
Duis sed commodo velit. \collectPhrase{Cras tempus} fermentum leo, ac congue nisl convallis vel.

\chapter{abc}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam metus massa, molestie elementum tincidunt at, mollis et quam.
Donec viverra posuere lorem, ac sagittis eros tincidunt interdum.
Phasellus feugiat id justo at pretium. \collectQuestion{Sed placerat sodales lorem sed sodales?}
Duis sed commodo velit. Cras tempus fermentum leo, \collectPhrase{ac congue nisl} convallis vel.
```

---

`.pdf` file
.
.
.

### Questions?

1. Donec viverra posuere lorem, ac sagittis eros tincidunt
   interdum?..pg x
2. Sed placerat sodales lorem sed
   sodales?........................................pg y

### Phrases:

1. Cras tempus (pg x)
2. ac congue nisl (pg y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please forgive me slight hints of irony:

["The Memoir Class"](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), which as the basic user manual of memoir has only 611 pages, says that one can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\listofphrasesname}{Phrases:}%
\newlistof{listofphrases}{phr}{\listofphrasesname}%
\newlistentry{phrase}{phr}{0}%
\cftpagenumbersoff{phrase}%
%
\newcounter{phrases}
\renewcommand{\thephrases}{\arabic{phrases}.}
\newcommand{\collectPhrase}[1]{%
  #1%
  \stepcounter{phrases}%
  \addcontentsline{phr}{phrase}{\protect\numberline{\thephrases}#1~(pg~\thepage)}%
} 


\newcommand{\listofquestionsname}{Questions?}%
\newlistof{listofquestions}{qst}{\listofquestionsname}%
\newlistentry{question}{qst}{0}%
\cftpagenumberson{question}%
%
\newcounter{questions}
\renewcommand{\thequestions}{\arabic{questions}.}
\newcommand{\collectQuestion}[1]{%
  #1%
  \stepcounter{questions}%
  \addcontentsline{qst}{question}{\protect\numberline{\thequestions}#1}%
}
\makeatletter
\newlength\mypagenumwidth
\settowidth\mypagenumwidth{\@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}pg~\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{}}%
\renewcommand\cftquestionformatpnumhook[4]{%
  \hb@xt@\mypagenumwidth{\hfil\@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}pg~#1}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{xyz}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
metus massa, molestie elementum tincidunt at, mollis et 
quam. \collectQuestion{Donec viverra posuere lorem, ac sagittis
eros tincidunt interdum?} Phasellus feugiat id justo at pretium.
Duis sed commodo velit. \collectPhrase{Cras tempus} fermentum
leo, ac congue nisl convallis vel.

\chapter{abc}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
metus massa, molestie elementum tincidunt at, mollis et
quam. Donec viverra posuere lorem, ac sagittis eros tincidunt
interdum. Phasellus feugiat id justo at
pretium. \collectQuestion{Sed placerat sodales lorem sed
sodales?} Duis sed commodo velit. Cras tempus fermentum leo,
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl} convallis vel.

\cleardoublepage
\listofquestions*

\listofphrases*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can do something that keeps track of the width of the number of the question/phrase/page and saves the width of the widest question-number/phrase-number/page-number into a label from which it can in future LaTeX-runs be retrieved for setting `\cftqestionnumwidth`/`\cftphrasenumwidth`/the width of the `\hbox` that contains the page number:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\listofphrasesname}{Phrases:}%
\newlistof{listofphrases}{phr}{\listofphrasesname}%
\newlistentry{phrase}{phr}{0}%
\cftpagenumbersoff{phrase}%
%
\newcounter{phrases}
\renewcommand{\thephrases}{\arabic{phrases}.}
\newlength\maxphrasenumwidth
\setlength\maxphrasenumwidth{0pt}%
\newcommand{\collectPhrase}[1]{%
  #1%
  \stepcounter{phrases}%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\@nameuse{cftphrasepagefont}\thephrases~}%
  \ifdim\@tempdima>\maxphrasenumwidth
    \setlength\maxphrasenumwidth\@tempdima
    \global\maxphrasenumwidth\maxphrasenumwidth
  \fi
  \endgroup
  \addcontentsline{phr}{phrase}{%
    \protect\numberline{\protect\hfill\thephrases\protect~}%
            #1\protect~(pg\protect~\thepage)%
  }%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifundefined{r@maxphrasenumwidth}{%
    \settowidth\cftphrasenumwidth{\@nameuse{cftphrasepagefont}100.~}%
  }{%
    \setlength\cftphrasenumwidth{\r@maxphrasenumwidth}%
  }%
}%
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{maxphrasenumwidth}{\the\maxphrasenumwidth}%
  }%
}%


\newlength\mypagenumwidth
\newlength\mypagenumsep
\newcommand{\listofquestionsname}{Questions?}%
\newlistof{listofquestions}{qst}{\listofquestionsname}%
\newlistentry{question}{qst}{0}%
\cftpagenumberson{question}%
\newcounter{questions}
\renewcommand{\thequestions}{\arabic{questions}.}
\newlength\maxquestnumwidth
\setlength\maxquestnumwidth{0pt}%
\newlength\maxpagenumwidth
\setlength\maxpagenumwidth{0pt}%
\newcommand{\collectQuestion}[1]{%
  #1%
  \stepcounter{questions}%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}\thequestions~}%
  \ifdim\@tempdima>\maxquestnumwidth
    \setlength\maxquestnumwidth\@tempdima
    \global\maxquestnumwidth\maxquestnumwidth
  \fi
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}pg~\thepage}%
  \ifdim\@tempdima>\maxpagenumwidth
    \setlength\maxpagenumwidth\@tempdima
    \global\maxpagenumwidth\maxpagenumwidth
  \fi
  \endgroup
  \addcontentsline{qst}{question}{%
    \protect\numberline{\protect\hfill\thequestions\protect~}#1%
  }%
}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidth\mypagenumsep{\@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}m}%
  \setlength\mypagenumsep{1.5\mypagenumsep}%
  \@ifundefined{r@maxquestnumwidth}{%
    \settowidth\cftquestionnumwidth{\@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}100.~}%
  }{%
    \setlength\cftquestionnumwidth{\r@maxquestnumwidth}%
  }%
  \@ifundefined{r@maxpagenumwidth}{%
    \settowidth\mypagenumwidth{%
      \@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}pg~\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{}%
    }%
  }{%
    \setlength\mypagenumwidth{\r@maxpagenumwidth}%
  }%
  \cftinsertcode{questionrightadjust}{%
     \setpnumwidth{\mypagenumwidth}%
     \setrmarg{\dimexpr\mypagenumsep+\mypagenumwidth\relax}%
  }%
  \cftinserthook{qst}{questionrightadjust}%
}%
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{maxquestnumwidth}{\the\maxquestnumwidth}%
  }%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{maxpagenumwidth}{\the\maxpagenumwidth}%
  }%
}%
\renewcommand\cftquestionformatpnumhook[4]{%
   \hb@xt@\mypagenumwidth{\@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}pg~#1\hfil}%
    %\hb@xt@\mypagenumwidth{\@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}pg\hfil#1}%
    %\hbox{\@nameuse{cftquestionpagefont}pg~#1}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{xyz}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
metus massa, molestie elementum tincidunt at, mollis et 
quam. \collectQuestion{Donec viverra posuere lorem, ac sagittis
eros tincidunt interdum?} Phasellus feugiat id justo at pretium.
Duis sed commodo velit. \collectPhrase{Cras tempus} fermentum
leo, ac congue nisl convallis vel.

\chapter{abc}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
metus massa, molestie elementum tincidunt at, mollis et
quam. Donec viverra posuere lorem, ac sagittis eros tincidunt
interdum. Phasellus feugiat id justo at
pretium. \collectQuestion{Sed placerat sodales lorem sed
sodales?} Duis sed commodo velit. Cras tempus fermentum leo,
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl} convallis vel.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.
\collectPhrase{ac congue nisl}.

\newpage\setcounter{page}{1000}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
metus massa, molestie elementum tincidunt at, mollis et quam.
\collectQuestion{Sed placerat sodales lorem sed
sodales?} \collectPhrase{Cras tempus} fermentum
leo, ac congue nisl convallis vel.


\cleardoublepage

\listofquestions*

\listofphrases*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write the questions and phrases at the end, in the order they appeared:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mdotfill}[1][1em]{%
  \leavevmode
  \linebreak[0]%
  \mbox{}\nobreak
  \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hskip #1 plus 1fill
  \kern\z@
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\collectQuestion}{m}
 {
  \naib_collect:Nnn \g_naib_collect_question_seq { #1 } { \mdotfill }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\collectPhrase}{m}
 {
  \naib_collect:Nnn \g_naib_collect_phrase_seq { #1 } { \nobreakspace }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printQuestions}{}
 {
  \begin{enumerate}
  \seq_use:Nn \g_naib_collect_question_seq {}
  \end{enumerate}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printPhrases}{}
 {
  \begin{enumerate}
  \seq_use:Nn \g_naib_collect_phrase_seq {}
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\int_new:N \g_naib_collect_int
\seq_new:N \g_naib_collect_question_seq
\seq_new:N \g_naib_collect_phrase_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \naib_collect:Nnn
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_naib_collect_int
  \label{ naib @ \int_to_roman:n { \g_naib_collect_int } }
  \naib_collect_append:Nenn
   #1
   { naib @ \int_to_roman:n { \g_naib_collect_int } } % the generated label
   { #2 } % the text
   { #3 } % the separation
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \naib_collect_append:Nnnn
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn #1 { \naib_collect_print:nnn {#2}{#3}{#4} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \naib_collect_append:Nnnn { Ne }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \naib_collect_print:nnn
 {
  \item #2#3(pg.\nobreakspace\pageref{#1})
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{xyz}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam metus massa, molestie elementum 
tincidunt at, mollis et quam.\collectQuestion{Donec viverra posuere lorem, ac sagittis eros tincidunt 
interdum feugiat?} Phasellus feugiat id justo at pretium. Duis sed commodo velit.\collectPhrase{Cras 
tempus} fermentum leo, ac congue nisl convallis vel.

\chapter{abc}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam metus massa, molestie elementum 
tincidunt at, mollis et quam. Donec viverra posuere lorem, ac sagittis eros tincidunt interdum. 
Phasellus feugiat id justo at pretium. \collectQuestion{Sed placerat sodales lorem sed sodales?} Duis 
sed commodo velit. Cras tempus fermentum leo, \collectPhrase{ac congue nisl} convallis vel.

\chapter{QP}

\section{Questions}

\printQuestions

\section{Phrases}

\printPhrases

\end{document}
```

[image]